# Loop through an SVG file in Javascript

Tags: javascript, svg, element

I'm trying to go through a rather basic SVG document with four `<rects>`, each with a unique ID. I want to add those elements to an array.

This is what I have...

```
    // event listner to make sure the page has loaded before running the scrupt
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
    // gets an SVG object from the inline HTML
    var svgObject = document.getElementById('rectTestSvg').contentDocument;

    var elementList = [];

    for(var i = 0; i < svgObject.numElements; i++){
        if(svgObject[i].id('*_rect') === true)
           {
           elementList.push(svgObject.getElementAt(i));
           }
    }

    console.log(elementList);
    });
```

It doesn't work past getting the svgObject, but hopefully it at least helps illustrate the idea.

Any help anyone could throw my way would be really appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In HTML5, SVG elements and their content are "just DOM elements", so queryselect the elements directly, and then form an array directly off of the result:

```
var myRects = Array.from(svgObject.querySelectorAll("rect"));
```

Done.

And the reason you want `Array.from` is because query selections are `NodeList` objects - while they're static (in this particular case, but most definitely not always so read the function documentation for functions you use!) they do not have any of the array functions that makes working with lists actually easy (`map`, `filter`, etc) so we turn it into an Array for writing normal code.

Do note that if your SVG object lives inside an iframe, you're almost guaranteed to not "just have access" to it, in which case you'll need to make sure the SVG document loads its own script that can talk to the parent page through a `window.postMessage()` channel (or websocket, but that's overkill).

Comment: Thanls for the reply, really set me in the correct direction.

I will note I had to make a small modification...

      
   `var myRects = Array.from(svgObject.querySelectorAll("rect"));`

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans `#rectTestSvg` is either an `<iframe>` or an `<object>` or an `<embed>` element. So they are right the querySelector should be `'rect'` from the contentDocument.

Comment: `svgObject = document.getElementById('rectTestSvg').contentDocument` only the three HTMLElements I listed above do have this `contentDocument` property. Yes HTML allows for inline `<svg>` content but doing so has not the same implications than loading it in a replaced element: there should be no id overlap, which means that an svg image can be loaded only once in the doc, if this svg image embeds its own stylesheets these will also leak on the rest of the doc etc. There are many cases where it is better to use a replaced element, and that's not the problem here.